# Why, after the London Fork, the average gas price of mined blocks is so lower than the needed gas price to have transactions included?

Tags: gas, gas-price, blocks, eip-1559

I understand the reason behind empty blocks but it seems to me that after the EIP-1559 the average gas prices of the transactions in the mined blocks are really low compared to what is the needed gas price to get a transaction included.

For example check the blocks that are being mined now: https://etherscan.io/blocks

For "now" I mean around the 12978365-th block. The average gas price is about 10gwei (but very volatile) nevertheless always according to Etherscan the average gas price is around 40.
Why? What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The price you see as 40 is the BaseFee (not sure if that includes the miner tips or not). The gas price that Etherscan shows in the blocks page refers to the miner payment (not counting the 2eth reward) divided by the total gas consumed in that block.

For instance, in block number `12978410` the gas consumed was `8,562,623` and the miner fees were `2 + 0.0737351771769214`. If you calculate:

> 0.0737351771769214*10**9 / 8,562,623 = 8.61 gwei

In summary, Etherscan shows 2 different gas prices: One is the `baseFee` and the other one is the implicit gas price taking into account the miner tips only.